# Expression of Type Scala.Predef.String doesn't conform to expected type String

Tags: string, scala

I have a function, **validateCell**, that takes a function, **func**, as one of its input parameters. It is as follows:

```
def validateCell[String](cellKey: String, cell: Option[String], func:(String) => Boolean): Tuple2[Boolean, String] = {
  cell match {
    case Some(cellContents)  => (func(cellContents), s"$cellContents is not valid.")
    case None => (false, s"$cellKey, not found.")
  }
}
```

I call the function as follows:

```
val map = Map("Well" -> "A110")
validateCell("Well", map.get("Well"), BarcodeWell.isValidWell)
```

The function that is passed in this case is as follows, though I don't think it's related to the problem:

```
def isValidWell(w: String): Boolean = {
  val row: String = w.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", "")
  val col: Int = w.replaceAll("[^0-9]+", "").toInt
  isValidRow(row) && isValidColumn(col)
}
```

I am expecting validateCell to return a Tuple(Boolean, String), but I get the following error:

```
Error:(5, 55) type mismatch;
 found   : java.lang.String
 required: String(in method validateCell)
    case Some(cellContents)  => (func(cellContents), s"$cellContents is not valid.")
```

I can make this error go away by converting the java strings in each tuple that are returned by the case statements to Scala strings like so:

```
s"$cellContents is not valid.".asInstanceOf[String]
s"$cellKey, not found.".asInstanceOf[String]
```

This seems really silly. What am I missing here? Shouldn't this conversion be handled by Scala automatically and why are my strings being cast as Java strings in the first place?

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference between Scala strings and Java strings. In fact, `Predef.String` aliases to `java.lang.String`. However, you're working with neither of these things; you're working with a type parameter.

```
def validateCell[String](cellKey: String, cell: Option[String], func:(String) => Boolean): Tuple2[Boolean, String] = {
```

This is a generic function which takes a type argument whose name is `String`. When you call `validateCell`, this type argument is being inferred and filled in for you, by something that definitely isn't a string. My guess is that you're misunderstanding the point of the brackets and that you meant to write

```
def validateCell(cellKey: String, cell: Option[String], func:(String) => Boolean): Tuple2[Boolean, String] = {
```

Comment: You guessed correctly! Thank you for the explanation.